# jquery appending bootstrap glyphicon to svg

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to append a glyphicon to an svg using:

```
$('.svgname').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Trash</button>');
```

It shows up in the svg when I use developer tools but does not actually show up on the page. I don't see any questions that directly help me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correctly appended to the DOM but it is not displayed on the page because SVG element simply shouldn't contain HTML elements.

[SVG](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp) is a container for elements describing the SVG graphics like this:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
</svg>
```

Any non-SVG elements (including HTML elements) within `svg` tag are ignored.

Take a look at these two JSFiddles:

[Correct SVG](http://jsfiddle.net/5cyL9L2u/).
[Incorrect SVG with HTML elements](http://jsfiddle.net/5cyL9L2u/1/).

They still look the same because browser ignores these elements while drawing SVG.

Comment: I see, thanks. Knowing this won't work is good. I'll up vote for future visitors.